# Very odd login behavior... PHP5, Session may be the culprit?

Tags: php, session, authentication

If you go to my main site: www.site.com, and then click "login" - you are taken to the login page: site.com/users/login.php.

At this point, the first time you try to login, and click submit, the page basically just reloads..  no error message (or successful login) is completed.

The 2nd (and 3rd, 4th, etc...) time, everything works like normal.  Additionally, for what seems to be the life of the session cookie (15 minutes), it still works normally.  If I close the browser, wait 15 minutes, and come back and do this process again, I'm back to the 1st time reload issue...

If I go directly to site.com/users/login.php, without coming from the main page link first, it works properly the first time...

I assume this is something to do with sessions?  Have you ever seen/heard of behavior like this?  I have no session active on the main page, only the /login.php page starts a session for the first time.

I know this probably isn't enough info to properly debug, but I thought I could at least throw it out there for people who have experienced something similar before....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Months later, the problem was solved.  Please see response here for the fix...

[session.cookie_domain in php.ini - issues with POSTing forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8451634/session-cookie-domain-in-php-ini-issues-with-posting-forms)