# session.cookie_domain in php.ini - issues with POSTing forms

Tags: session, cookies, php

My main domain: `www.domain.com` has a cookie which is set as: `domain.com`.

Once a user clicks the link to visit `www.domain.com/login`, and they try to log in (through a POST request), this form sets the cookie as `www.domain.com` (adds the www).  This is causing issues with many people because when they submit the login form, the page just refreshes.

For some people, it does this FOREVER (can never submit the form).  For others, it's only once - and the 2nd time, it works fine.  It also varies by browser...

What is my fix here, I assume I need to enter something into my `session.cookie_domain in php.ini` - but what is the correct course of action?

Thanks all.

---**UPDATE**---
Code to set the cookie on the login page:

```
$expireTime = 60 * 60 * .5; // 30 minute expire time
session_set_cookie_params($expireTime,"/");
session_start();
```

Comment: Please include the actual code you're using to set the cookie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to explicitly set the domain, *without* the www, but with the preceding dot, as the third param to that function.

session_set_cookie_params($expireTime,"/", ".yourdomain.com");

This will allow the cookies to work the same regardless of whether the www is present in the actual URL or not. Note that this also applies to any other subdomains you may use, which is usually a good thing, just putting it out there.

Comment: I can also just set ".yourdomain.com" in my php.ini file, no?

Comment: Yes, you could alternately / also set session.cookie_domain in the INI to this value.